# convert custom collection to DataRow

Tags: c#, devexpress, datarow, xtragrid

I try to pass the value to DataRow type variable from custom collection like the codes bellow:

```
GridHitInfo downHitInfo = null;
DataRow row = gridView3.GetDataRow(downHitInfo.RowHandle);
```

But as I know that if the view's data source is a custom collection of objects, the `GetDataRow` method returns `null` (Nothing in Visual Basic). If the view's data is supplied by the `System.Data.DataTable` or `System.Data.DataView object`, the `System.Data.DataRow object` representing a specific row is returned."

And the XPCollection is "a custom collection of objects".

Is there any way that I could do to get the value from

```
gridView3.GetDataRow(downHitInfo.RowHandle)?
```

Is there any converter or something needed?

Comment: See my answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762617/how-to-get-the-selected-row-values-of-devexpress-xtragrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the DataRow object when the underlying Grid's data source not is DataTable or DataView. When the data source's type is XPCollection you should use the [GetRow()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic) method instead of the [GetDataRow()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataRowtopic) method to get objects which correspond to grid rows:

```
var xpCollection = new XPCollection<Person>();
gridControl1.DataSource = xpCollection;
//...
Person person = (Person)gridView1.GetRow(rowHandle);
```

Comment: "You can't get the DataRow object when the underlying Grid's data source not is DataTable or DataView."...I don't believe that is correct.