# How to get the selected row values of DevExpress XtraGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

Consider the following picture

[image]

I get the selected row values in the three textboxes shown in the figure when i click a cell using following code.

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    TBGRNo.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    TBSName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    TBFName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```

My Question is: how will I do the same thing in DevExpress XtraGrid control??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways. You can use databinding (typical initialized after InitializeComponent();)

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", yourBindingSource, 
                    "TableName.ColumnName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

or use a DataLayoutControl (if you are going to use textbox for editing, I really recommend spending some time to learn how to use this component.

or in FocusedRowChanged by assigning from one of these methods:

```
textBox1.Text = gridView1.GetDataRow(e.FocusedRowHandle)["Name"].ToString();
textBox1.Text = gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow()["Name"].ToString();
textBox1.Text = (gridView1.GetFocusedRow() as DataRowView).Row["Name"].ToString();
textBox1.Text = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Name").ToString();
```

Answer (score 30):

Here is the way that I've followed,

```
int[] selRows = ((GridView)gridControl1.MainView).GetSelectedRows();
DataRowView selRow = (DataRowView)(((GridView)gridControl1.MainView).GetRow(selRows[0]));
txtName.Text = selRow["name"].ToString();
```

Also you can iterate through selected rows using the selRows array. Here the code describes how to get data only from first selected row. You can insert these code lines to click event of the grid.

Comment: look at my own answer about my question. that is probably simpler and esier

Comment: Yes, your answer is easier. But I was trying to get details from all selected rows (with multiple selection). So I change this answer to match with your question. So thank you for your answer. I hope this may help to somebody!

Comment: @kashif yo don't have to be mean to show that your answer is a better fit for your case.

Comment: how do I do this in wpf. can you plz answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393926

Comment: Sorry kashif. I am no longer using DevExpress. hope you will get an answer soon from another DevExpress expert.

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution as follows:

```
private void gridView1_RowCellClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellClickEventArgs e)
{
    TBGRNo.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "GRNo").ToString();
    TBSName.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "SName").ToString();
    TBFName.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FName").ToString();            
}
```

[image]

Comment: This Work 100% ... Thanks Kashif

Answer (score 5):

Which one of their Grids are you using? XtraGrid or AspXGrid? Here is a piece taken from one of my app using XtraGrid.

```
private void grdContactsView_RowClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
{
    _selectedContact = GetSelectedRow((DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView)sender);
}

private Contact GetSelectedRow(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view)
{
    return (Contact)view.GetRow(view.FocusedRowHandle);
}
```

My Grid have a list of Contact objects bound to it. Every time a row is clicked I load the selected row into _selectedContact. Hope this helps. You will find lots of information on using their controls buy visiting their support and documentation sites.

Comment: Having found the solution I answered my question myself. Anyways thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

For VB.Net

```
CType(GridControl1.MainView, GridView).GetFocusedRow()
```

For C#

```
((GridView)gridControl1.MainView).GetFocusedRow();
```

example bind data by linq so use

```
Dim selRow As CUSTOMER = CType(GridControl1.MainView, GridView).GetFocusedRow()
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is use the **GetFocusedRowCellValue** method of the gridView control and put it into the RowClick event.

For example:

```
private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.gvCodigoNombres.GetFocusedRowCellValue("EMP_dni") == null)
        return;
    MessageBox.Show(""+this.gvCodigoNombres.GetFocusedRowCellValue("EMP_dni").ToString());            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowHandle = gridView.FocusedRowHandle;

var obj = gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "FieldName");

//For example  
int val= Convert.ToInt32(gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "FieldName"));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18436116).