# How to get Focused Row colunm value into EdtiText when I click on the Focused Row ?? Winforms Devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have Gridview and 6 rows in it. Now I want to get the Focused Row Column value when I click any Cells in Corresponding Row. For Example I want to get Student Exam_no, If i click Student name , Address or Department any cell in the same Row I want to get Exam_no. How to Complete my Task ?

```
  private void gridControl2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new New_Invoice();
        frm.Show();
        gridView1.RefreshData();
    }
```

This code i tried but not work what I except ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762617/how-to-get-the-selected-row-values-of-devexpress-xtragrid) for exampels

Comment: Hi Jens Kloster, Ok i get Row Focused Value now, but my task is that I want the value in another Form. How to get that particular value into Another Form ?

Comment: I would send it via the constructor, something like `new New_Invoice(yourValue);` and then `public New_Invoice(string val)` etc.

Comment: Hi I used Constructor but now error come like this Object Reference not set ti Instance on Object ?

Comment: My code is this `public partial class New_Invoice : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        
        string getOper = "A";
 
        public New_Invoice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        public New_Invoice(string oper, int invoiceno)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
           
            textEdit5.Text = invoiceno.ToString(); // error shown in this line
            textEdit5.Visible = false;
            getOper = oper;
        }`

Comment: Add `InitializeComponent();` as the fist thing, in you new copnstructor

Comment: You shoud ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick

    Dim myColumn As String = e.Column.FieldName ' for the datasource column name
           Dim myValue = GridView1.GetFocusedDataRow(myColumn)

    'For a standard one column
    myValue = view.GetFocusedDataRow("ColumnX")

End Sub
```