# C# Windows Form and devExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

How to get the current Cell in Grid Control and return cell in textbox?

Comment: What do you mean by this "and return cell in textbox" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the selected row values of DevExpress XtraGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762617/how-to-get-the-selected-row-values-of-devexpress-xtragrid)

Comment: When I want in all your press Double  in GridControl1 In the selected item is submitted to the textbox So I edited it

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want XtraGrid's current cell value in textbox.

So for that retrieve cell value by -

```
// <gridView> is name of GridView
<gridView>.GetRowCellValue(<gridView>.FocusedRowHandle, <aFieldName>);
```

or if you are trying to get cell's *text*, go as follow -

```
string cellValue = gridView1.GetFocusedDisplayText();
```

For more, please refer DevExpress documentation - [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753)

Comment: If it was helpful, please mark it as answer so that it can be helpful to other users. ;)