# How to get the selected row values of DevExpress GridControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I asked [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbSfn.png) question in Oct, 2012 when I was working on windows application. now when I turn to WPF application, I get the same problem again i.e How to get the selected row values of DevExpress GridControl in **WPF**?  I've failed to find my answer on google and none of the answers in the above mentioned link is working. there is nothing like CellClick,  RowClick or RowCellClick event in devexpress gridcontrol of wpf as it is in winform gridcontrol. I'll be glad if someone can solve out this problem

**Edit**

I have updated my application with required namespaces as you updated in your answer but the problem remains the same. i'm getting following tow errors in

```
<Grid.DataContext>
        <dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type="{x:Type local:EntitiesViewModel}"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
```

1- the type 'dxmvvm:ViewModelSource'" was not found in dxmvvm:ViewModelSource

2-  name "EntitiesViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:DXApplication1"

my application coding is as follows

XAML

```
<dx:DXWindow
    x:Class="DXApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DXApplication1"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
    Title="DXApplication" Height="700" Width="1100"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True">

    <dx:DXWindow.Resources>
    </dx:DXWindow.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="12">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type="{x:Type local:EntitiesViewModel}"/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,8">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Item1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Content="Item2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Content="Item3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Item1}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Item2}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Item3}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" 
                     AutoGenerateColumns="None" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item1"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item2"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item3"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True" AllowEditing="False"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</dx:DXWindow>
```

EntitiesViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DXApplication1
{
    public class EntitiesViewModel
    {
        public EntitiesViewModel()
        {
            LoadEntities();
        }
        void LoadEntities()
        {
            Entities = new ObservableCollection<Entity>
        {
            new Entity(){ Item1="A", Item2="A0", Item3="A00"},
            new Entity(){ Item1="B", Item2="B0", Item3="B00"},
            new Entity(){ Item1="C", Item2="C0", Item3="C00"},
        };
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Entity> Entities { get; private set; }
        public virtual Entity SelectedEntity { get; set; } // Bindable property
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        public string Item2 { get; set; }
        public string Item3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Image for libraries, error, class etc

[image]

Comment: In WPF, it is wrong way to use events for obtaining values from grid and propagating these values into editors, rather than just use data-bindings...

Comment: @Dmitry this is not a right way to answer to a wpf biginer. you should answer with code example properly as nempo did so that one can follow your way. telling to a biginer to use databinding is not enough

Comment: All I want, is just prevent you from using the habitual approaches despite of the target platform change, instead of learning the platform... The right way is to ask right questions and to demonstrate your attempts and results...

Comment: @DmitryG I'm sorry for the way I asked my question. please see my update and tell me the right way of getting selected row values from gridctrol in the mentioned textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataControlBase.CurrentItemChanged`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CurrentItemChangedtopic) event.
Here is example:
**WPF:**

```xml
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridControl1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" CurrentItemChanged="gridControl1_CurrentItemChanged">
</dxg:GridControl>
```

**Event handler:**

```
private void gridControl1_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TBGRNo.Text = gridControl1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("GRNo").ToString();
    TBSName.Text = gridControl1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("SName").ToString();
    TBFName.Text = gridControl1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("FName").ToString();    
}
```

Comment: @kashif Yes, In WPF there are `GridControl.GetFocusedRowCellValue` method and in WinForms there are `GridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue` method.

Comment: if there is a single row in girdview, the solution that you provided doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the selection topic in the documentation at the Devexpress Homepage:
[Grid Selection Topic](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7361)

If you are using the MVVM pattern you should also have a look at the 
[SelectedItems Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_SelectedItemstopic).
The example there shows how to bind to the selected items:

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" SelectedItems="{Binding Selection}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as follows

```
<Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl Name="gridcontrol" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="315" Width="575">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item1"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item2"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item3"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="gridview" ShowTotalSummary="True" AllowEditing="False"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
    <dxe:TextEdit Name="TBItem1" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Item1, ElementName=gridcontrol, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
    <dxe:TextEdit Name="TBItem2" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Item2, ElementName=gridcontrol, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
    <dxe:TextEdit Name="TBItem3" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Item3, ElementName=gridcontrol, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
    <Label Content="Item1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48"/>
    <Label Content="Item2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Item3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Dmitry is it fine now? if yes, I'm really greatfull to you

Comment: Hi! Now it looks much better to me, but there are some point to improve (strong dependencies between View' controls, "fixed" layout)... Take a look at my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're want to display list of entities, then provide an UI for selecting one of these entitites (via gridcontrol) and edit the selected entity properties in separate view (via text editors).

So, I suggest you to use the MVVM approach. And, since you are already using DevExpress controls, I suggest you use the [DevExpress MVVM Framework](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15112) to make your MVVM as easy as it possible.

Step 1: Define a ViewModel class that contains your entities collection available via the `Entities` property (you can load these entities in way as it needed, from it needed and when it needed) and provide the `SelectedEntity` property:

```
public class EntitiesViewModel {
    public EntitiesViewModel() {
        LoadEntities();
    }
    void LoadEntities() {
        Entities = new ObservableCollection<Entity>
        {
            new Entity(){ Item1="A", Item2="A0", Item3="A00"},
            new Entity(){ Item1="B", Item2="B0", Item3="B00"},
            new Entity(){ Item1="C", Item2="C0", Item3="C00"},
        };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Entity> Entities { get; private set; }
    public virtual Entity SelectedEntity { get; set; } // Bindable property
}
public class Entity {
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2: Define a View layout as follows:

```
...
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DXApplication1"
xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
...
<Grid Margin="12">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type="{x:Type local:EntitiesViewModel}"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Item1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="Item2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="Item3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Item1}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Item2}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Item3}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" 
                     AutoGenerateColumns="None" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item1"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item2"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Item3"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True" AllowEditing="False"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
</Grid>
```

*The main points-of-interest and tricks are:
1) creating the `EntitiesViewModel` instance via the ViewModelSource. This way allows you do not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface at the ViewModel's level - you can just declare the `SelectedEntity` property as `virtual` and delegate all the dirty-work to the [POCO mechanism](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17352):

```
<dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type="{x:Type local:EntitiesViewModel}"/>
```

2) all View' controls bindings are "looks" into the DataContext (which contains our ViewModel):

```
...
Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Item1}"
...
ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}">
```

This way allows you to decouple all UI-controls from each other and modify the View with easy.

Comment: im getting error hear <Grid.DataContext>
        <dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type="{x:Type local:EntitiesViewModel}"/>
    </Grid.DataContext> can you plz provide the complete xaml coding

Comment: @kashif I've updated my answer with required xaml-namespaces(please also ensure that the DevExpress.Mvvm.vXX.X.dll library added in project references).

Comment: I'm sorry to annoy you again. I'm really curious and enthusiastic in learning what you r instructing. the problem still persists. can you plz upload your project somewhere for me to download. plzz see my edited question for my problem

Comment: @kashif I see from your updated question  that you are using the old version (v13.1) - please try to use the latest one (v15.1). I'm using the latest version and I do not know whether or not my code will work with old version(I believe not, because there is no DevExpress.Mvvm library in this version) .

Comment: I see the `DevExpress.Xpf.Mvvm` on your screenshots, and this is absolutely another library... Anyway, you wrote that you are using the cracked version. If so, you should start from resolving the issue with violating the US and international laws...